# How can i save all the data from my little sign up page and display them

Tags: javascript, html, css

Well the question is the same with the title. Please help me, code is just below. I'd like to save all the data from textboxes, radio, age and display it somewhere else as if it is a sign up page. Any thoughts?

Html part:

```
<div id="nameC">Name:</div> <input type="text" maxlength="8" id="name" onkeypress="return ifnumberrr(event);" />
    <div id="lnameC">Last Name:</div> <input type="text" maxlength="10" id="lname" onkeypress="return ifnumberrrr(event);" />
    <div id="ageC">Age:</div> <input type="text" id="age" onkeypress="return ifnumber(event);" maxlength="2" />
    <div id="genderT">Gender:</div>
    <div class="genderM">Male 
    <input type="radio" id="gender" name="genderrr" />
    </div>
    <div class="genderF">Female
    <input type="radio" id="gender" name="genderrr" />
    </div>
    <div id="button"><input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" /></div>
```

Css part:

```
<style>
        .genderM {
            position: fixed;
            left: 175px;
            top: 130px;
        }
        .rdGender {
            position: absolute;
            left: 175px;
        }
        #button {
            position: absolute;
            top: 200px;
            left: 155px;
        }
        #genderT{
            position:fixed;
            top: 130px;
        }
        #nameC {
            position:fixed;
            top: 10px;
        }
        #lnameC{
            position:fixed;
            top: 50px;
        }
        #name{
            position:fixed;
            left: 175px;
            top: 10px;
        }
        #lname{
            position:fixed;
            left: 175px;
            top: 50px;
        }
        #ageC{
            position:fixed;
            top: 90px;
        }
        #age{
            position:fixed;
            left: 175px;
            top: 90px;
        }
        .genderF{
            position:fixed;
            top: 130px;
            left: 245px;
        }
    </style>
```

Javascript part:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function ifnumber(evt) {
        evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
        if(charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode >57)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    function ifnumberrr(e) {
        var alphabet;
        if (!e) var e = window.event;
        if (e.keyCode) alphabet = e.keyCode;
        else if (e.which) alphabet = e.which;
        if ((alphabet >= 48) && (alphabet <= 57)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
}

    function ifnumberrrr(e) {
        var alphabet;
        if (!e) var e = window.event;
        if (e.keyCode) alphabet = e.keyCode;
        else if (e.which) alphabet = e.which;
        if ((alphabet >= 48) && (alphabet <= 57)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: use serialize array to get entire form inputs , refer this   https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, checking it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello @Altay Mazlum to achieve this you can use php and MySql. while you submit your form using php it creates values and using the insert method you insert them into an SQL database.

After doing so you can call the values using also php echo function.

- So the steps to follow are the below:

  - create an SQL database
  - submit the form using php
  - on submit the values are inserted into rows in ur sql table
  - on call retrieve data using php and print them on page.

Comment: We Can always help you whenever you encounter a problem while trying. @altay Mazlum

Answer (score 0):

You can more your controls in `<form/> tag`. Give them name and use [`.serializeArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/).

```js
function ifnumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function ifnumberrr(e) {
    var alphabet;
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e.keyCode) alphabet = e.keyCode;
    else if (e.which) alphabet = e.which;
    if ((alphabet >= 48) && (alphabet <= 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function ifnumberrrr(e) {
    var alphabet;
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e.keyCode) alphabet = e.keyCode;
    else if (e.which) alphabet = e.which;
    if ((alphabet >= 48) && (alphabet <= 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function getFormText() {
    alert(JSON.stringify($("form").serializeArray()));
    return false;
}
```

```css
.genderM {
    position: fixed;
    left: 175px;
    top: 130px;
}
.rdGender {
    position: absolute;
    left: 175px;
}
#button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 155px;
}
#genderT {
    position:fixed;
    top: 130px;
}
#nameC {
    position:fixed;
    top: 10px;
}
#lnameC {
    position:fixed;
    top: 50px;
}
#name {
    position:fixed;
    left: 175px;
    top: 10px;
}
#lname {
    position:fixed;
    left: 175px;
    top: 50px;
}
#ageC {
    position:fixed;
    top: 90px;
}
#age {
    position:fixed;
    left: 175px;
    top: 90px;
}
.genderF {
    position:fixed;
    top: 130px;
    left: 245px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form onsubmit="return getFormText()">
    <div id="nameC">Name:</div>
    <input type="text" maxlength="8" id="name" name="fname" onkeypress="return ifnumberrr(event);" />
    <div id="lnameC">Last Name:</div>
    <input type="text" maxlength="10" id="lname" name="lname" onkeypress="return ifnumberrrr(event);" />
    <div id="ageC">Age:</div>
    <input type="text" id="age" name="age" onkeypress="return ifnumber(event);" maxlength="2" />
    <div id="genderT">Gender:</div>
    <div class="genderM">Male
        <input type="radio" id="gender" name="genderrr" />
    </div>
    <div class="genderF">Female
        <input type="radio" id="gender" name="genderrr" />
    </div>
    <div id="button">
        <input type="submit" value="Click ME" id="submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks much, i'll give it a try with this one

Comment: @AltayMazlum give it up vote and mark answer if solves broblem